# How do I put a border on only the top and bottom of an image in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2010

I upgraded to Word 2010 (from Word 2003), and am no longer able to apply only top and bottom borders to photos and charts that are inserted or copied into my document as pictures.  I used to use the *Table Border tool* to place borders around whichever part of the image I want, but now I can only apply a border to all four sides of the image at once.

Is there any way to apply a border *only* to the top and bottom of an image using Word 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could find to do what you want is to make a table of one cell that is exactly the same size as the image and put the borders on that.  It turns out looking like this:

[image: smiley face with borders]

But that's pretty fiddly to do.  Hopefully someone else knows an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's still the same way, if I understood your question

1. Insert your picture.
2. Select the line (not the picture, clicking in the left edge of the page)
3. Use the paragraph tool to set top and bottom borders

It's done!

Comment: Perhaps if you add some screen caps it will be more clear what the exact steps are ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The steps in Word 2010 to apply borders to an image are pretty close to those of [Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-borders-to-text-tables-and-pictures-HA010275645.aspx?CTT=1).  In particular, you basically need to get into the borders and shading dialog box, where it lets you really customize the style of each side's border.